# Courant-Hilbert's Book: Weyl's asymptotic law for eigenvalues - Planar domains

Tags: reference-request, spectral-theory

In the book Strauss W.A. *Partial Differential Equations - an Introduction* (Wiley, 2008, 1st Ed.) page $311$, there is a comment

> Now an arbitrary plane domain $D$ can be approximated by unions of rectangles just as in the construction of a double integral (and as in Section $8.4$). With the help of Theorem $5$, it is possible to prove Theorem 1 (i.e. $(1)$ is Weyl's asymptotic law for eigenvalues on planar domain). The details are omitted but the proof may be found in [CH].

I'm trying actually to find the proof of $(1)$ in the book *Methods of Mathematical Physics (Volume II)* of Courant-Hilbert, but it is not clear where it is. Is there anyone could help me to find the page in that book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong volume.

You should look in Vol I, Chapter VI, Section 4, Subsection 4 starting on page 436. The title of that section is "Asymptotic Distribution of Eigenvalues for an Arbitrary Domain".

Good luck!